# Detect cancelled form post with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm working on a web project that has a lot of abstraction - lots of code is squirreled away in view templates, internal company javascript libraries, etc.

I have been asked to "hijack" the form submit buttons to disable them when the form is submitted, to disallow extra clicks. The problem is, I still have to submit the button as it's used in 99% of our system as a form input (not best practices, but I didn't write that code!)

What I have done is when the user clicks "Save," that button is hidden using jQuery and an exact duplicate that is disabled with a spinner icon is put in its place:

```
function showSpinningButton(button){
    $(button).hide();

    clone = $(button).clone();

    clone.prop('disabled', true);

    $(button).parent().append(clone);
    clone.show();
}
```

This works in the standard use case, but the niche case is validation - there is no way for me to detect when the form is invalid and the button needs to be reset to standard. This is especially troublesome as all the validation is done in external-facing Javascript libraries that I am not allowed to modify.

The gist is this: is there a DOM event that is fired when a form that had been submitted is cancelled (i.e. onclick="return false;") that I could attach a handler to to reset the button?

Comment: html5 validation can be checked at any time. if you're using js-based validation it's the wild-west, but there's probably a way to run the validation other than onsubmit; check the validation library docs. that said, you can likely just hide the button onsubmit instead of swapping it out like that.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a wrapper on the validation function:

```
var oldHandler = form.prop("onsubmit");
form.removeProp("onsubmit").submit(function(e) {
  var result = oldHandler.call(this, e);
  if (result == false) {
    // reset your button
  }
  return result;
});
```