# HTML/JavaScript: Programmatically detect that form submit was cancelled

Tags: javascript, html

I have a webpage for users to enter data in input fields. In the form submit event JavaScript code is used to "standardize" the input fields, such as converting the user's MM/DD/YYYY style dates into YYYY-MM-DD format. Unfortunately, if other JavaScript code (most likely [jQuery Validation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/)) executes after mine and cancels the submittal, the fields will remain in the standardized format instead of the user's format.

Is there a way to programmatically detect that the submit was cancelled (so that JavaScript code could revert the input fields)? If not, is there a way to ensure that my code is the last to run? If not, is there another way to work around this problem?

Note: This question is similar to the one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24959843/2615878). Unfortunately, there are no answers for it yet.

**EDIT**

The following code is the standardize-the-date code that I mentioned above. It uses jQuery and Moment.js but has no idea that jQuery Validate is being used. I would like to keep it ignorant of jQuery Validate if possible.

```
$("form").submit(function () {
    // For each date field...
    $("input[type=date]").each(function () {
        // ...get its value...
        var $dateField = $(this);
        var day = moment($dateField.val());

        // ...and, if it is recognized, ...
        if (day.isValid()) {
            // ...convert it to the "standard" format.
            $dateField.val(day.format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Why do you have other code that you don't control on your site? (i mean the "most likely jQuery Validation" part). I think you should run the validation first, and then standardize the inputs and then send it out

Comment: Why don't you handle the JQuery Validation's `invalidHandler` function callback. It will tell you if the submit failed due to it...

Comment: @JonasGrumann: Doesn't jQuery validation run on the submit event? If it does, then how can I make it run before my code which is also triggered on the submit? (Please note that my JavaScript code is now included in the question.)

Comment: @LcSalazar: I'm under the impression that `invalidHandler` may run after my JavaScript code has already completed. Am I mistaken?